# How to display image from path file?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have image saved from my device. I stored the path file of the image in my local database. How can I load the image using the path file?

Here is my code:

```
 <Image StyleClass="thumbnail" x:Name="media1thumb" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

 var media1 = mediaResult.MediaMobilePath1;

 media1thumb.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
 {
     var stream = media1.GetStream();
     media1.Dispose();
     return stream;
 });
```

Comment: maybe this article will be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @P10trek please see update code

Comment: You want to load an image using its path correct?

Comment: @G.hakim yes the path is in the media1

Comment: And the above code is not working for you?

Comment: ImageSource.FromFile(path);